# Create Graph sharing axes Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 4 columns. The first column represents the days, and the three other columns are names of students. The student will have a value 100 if he attended on a certain day and 0 if he is absent. I wonder how I can plot this data in python?

This is how I want it to look like where there are multiple x axis for each student. I also included a sample photo of the data on the right and a sample csv file can be found here: [**CSV SAMPLE FILE**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/935ire5boaqcg0c/Graph_.csv?dl=0):
[image]

Comment: Use subgraphs, perhaps?

Comment: @DYZ Not sure how...I've updated the question

Comment: The page that you referenced at the end of the question has the source code for all pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar result in terms of sharing the axes as shown in this [link](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html):
[image]

```
# Three subplots sharing both x/y axes
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Sharing both axes')
ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax3.scatter(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
```